# "Type Mismatch" error when executing Excel Macro

Tags: .net, excel, excel-2010, vba

I have created a Macro to remove all borders from empty rows in my excel file. this is mig code:

```
Sub RemoveRows()
'
' RemoveRows Macro
'

'
    Range("A8").Select

    Dim checkval

    Dim RowAmount
    RowAmount = 93



    Do
        checkval = ActiveCell.Value
        If (checkval = "" Or checkval = Null) Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
        RowAmount = RowAmount - 1
    Loop While RowAmount > 0


End Sub
```

method for running the macro:

```
public void RemoveRows_Macro(string fileName)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = true;

    //Run the macro
    xlApp.Run("RemoveRows", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

    xlWorkBook.Save();

    xlWorkBook.Close(false);
    xlApp.Quit();
    releaseObject(xlApp);
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
}
```

My problem is that i can run this macro from my C# application without getting this error, but when others use my C# application they get this error: **Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch**

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Please show us how you run the macro?
Also, in which place occurs the error?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3etdkytt(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: This code runs as expected directly from the vba in Excel 2010.

Comment: The macro runs also perfectly from my computer when i run it. But when the macro runs on some (not all) machines this error occurs. Error occurs on this line : **If (checkval = "" Or checkval = Null) Then**

Comment: Microsoft documentation recommends `IsEmpty()` as the test to apply to `Range.Value`.

Comment: i think its because of the cell formatting. if i use 0 instead og "" it runs without any errors, but it does not remove the empty rows

Comment: Checking a cell for `Null` is pointless, as a cell cannot be `Null`.  They can be `Empty`.  Note that all `Empty` cells also `= ""`, but not all cells that `= ""` are `Empty`

Comment: isEmpty(checkval) doesnt do anything. only if i run it with checkval="" it removes the empty rows.

Comment: I cant use checkval = "" that is when i am getting the type mismatch error

Answer (score 1):

Try this version

It deals with

- possible entries that *apear* as empty cells but arn't (deletes them)
- Formula's that return `""` (leaves them)
- greatly improves run time

---

```
Sub RemoveRows()
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng As Range, rngDel As Range
    Dim str As String

    Set rng = Range("A8:A100")
    dat = rng.Formula

    For i = 1 To UBound(dat, 1)
        str = Replace$(dat(i, 1), Chr(160), "")
        str = Replace$(str, vbCr, "")
        str = Replace$(str, vbLf, "")
        str = Replace$(str, vbTab, "")
        If Len(Trim$(str)) = 0 Then
            If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngDel = rng.Cells(i, 1)
            Else
                Set rngDel = Application.Union(rngDel, rng.Cells(i, 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then
        rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems like a painful way to do a, "if blank delete". Thanks microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

To stay away from cell formatting always use `Value2`.

Always dimension the variables type, and use them when needed only, checkval isnt very usefull, you can directly check for `ActiveCell.Value2 = ""` or check `IsEmpty(ActiveCell)`.

If you really want to use this variable than dimension it as `Variant`.

Excel cell values are not NULL, they are at least empty or equal to an empty string (""), so doing the `IsNull` or `= NULL` check dont make sense in VBA. Skip the check for Null and it should work fine.

Comment: that didnt help. The issue is when i use checkval = "" when i use isEmpty(checkval) the error doesnt occur, but it doesnt remove the empty rows

Comment: i am running the isEmpty on my template document. The document is sent to me by my boss. I should maybe check for white space istead ?

Comment: IF the target cells contain a space (" ") then you should check for those, it is impossible for us to tell you, we dont have your spreadsheet ;)

Comment: I just did a white space test. and that didnt remove the rows. the only thing that removes the rows is **checkval = ""** but as this works on my laptop, it does not work on others.

Comment: Ive just seen a good way to test, use `len(trim(checkval)) = 0`. It seems fool proof.

Comment: When doing the validation on checkvalue you might remove cells that have a formula in them with outcome ="", which isnt the same as an empty cell (as it contains a formula)...

Comment: @K_B, now your trying to mash my brain ;) what happens in thoes cases? Are the results classed as empty?

Comment: Here is the excel sheet: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=D9D07A25D7BC1662!715

Answer (score -2):

A couple of things to try:

1. It is good practice to declare your  variable types, in this case `string` or `variant` or `range`.
2. Try to use the `IsNull(checkval)` function instead of `checkval = Null`.

   - As @Chris states, a cell is indeed `Empty` not `null`, use `isempty(a)`.
   - **After some diding into this, what seems to be a common issue, I've come across a great solution that seems fool proof, use `len(trim(a)) = 0` as the check.**
3. It is unnecessary to cycle through the cells by selecting them:

Code:

```
Sub RemoveRows() 
'
' RemoveRows Macro 
'

' 

    Dim checkval as long, RowAmount as long
    checkval = 8
    RowAmount = 93

    Do 

        'If trim(range("A" & checkval)) = "" Or _
        '       isempty(range("A" & checkval)) Then 'thanks chris
        If Len(Trim(range("A" & checkval))) = 0 then 
            range("A" & checkval).EntireRow.Delete 
        Else 
            checkval  = checkval + 1
        End if
        RowAmount = RowAmount - 1 

    Loop While RowAmount > 0

End Sub
```

Comment: thank u for the help. I just tried ur example, and i get the same error at this line: **If range("A" & checkval) = "" Or isnull(range("A" & checkval)) Then** i think its because of the cell formatting. if i use 0 instead og "" it runs without any errors, but it does not remove the empty rows.

Comment: Checking for both `= ""` and `IsEmpty` is unnecessary.  As I said earlier _all `Empty` cells are also `= ""`_.  While `Trim` will deal with normal spaces (ascii 32) it does not deal with non printable characters ascii > 255 (eg non-break spaces ascii 160).  While I agree using `Select` is a generally bad idea, your use of `Range` isn't much better. If you must use a Range, use `For Each cl in Range("A8:A100")`

Comment: @chrisneilsen, since he is deleting entire rows this will skip the following cell from this loop, e.g. while in A8 and you delete A8, A9 will become A8 and then the for loop will skip A9 effectively going to A10, what then? This is why i didn't choose this option.

Comment: here is the excel sheet: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=D9D07A25D7BC1662!715